# How to find the last element in an array in python for both regular arrays and python?

Tags: python

When using len(array) -1, I get an error that array has no len
when using array[-1],

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something like `x = 3; len(x)` or `x = 3; x[-1]`. `array` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Post the code that creates `array`, it is probably not an indexable type

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code where this happens?

Comment: array starts off as a numpy array of zeros, and is then filled using a model that involves other ararys. I don't think posting the code that creates array will help, just a general concept clarification

Comment: Please share [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are doing.  It sounds like, as everyone else has said, you are not doing what you think you are doing.  But until we see your code, we can't help.

Answer (score 2):

Your are right that it is the correct method to retrieve the last element for array in both regular Python array and Numpy array.

Regular array:

```
ary = [1,2,4]
ary[-1]
>>> 4
len(ary)
>>> 3
```

Numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

ary = np.array([1,2,4])
ary[-1]
>>> 4
```

As for the reason you got the

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

, from the description provided in your comment, the most likely cause is that you applied the `len()` function and the index on a 'non-array' object in Numpy. In the following example, `ary` is a *Numpy* array, but `ary[0]` is just an *integer*, not an array object.

```
ary = np.array([1,2,4])

len(ary[0][1])
>>> TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()

ary[0][1]
>>> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `array[array.length()-1]`

`length()-1`  stands for the last element because indexing starts from 0